# Accessing movieclips within movieclip using For statement (AS3)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am trying to access movieclips within my movieclip using a for statement. To try and make this clear, here is how it looks at the moment:

**sections** = Holder movieclip where dtf_sections is placed, as well as other clips that are needed.

**dtf_sections** = Where all the title movieclips are placed that are going to be used when called. Placed in here to make it easier to move, within **sections**

**title** = Movieclip that contains the text that needs to be changed, within **dtf_sections**

Here is my code that works:

```
sections.dtf_sections.title1.dtf_title.text = "Section 1"
```

There are upto 10 titles within dtf_sections. So, what I thought would work is this:

```
for(var i:uint=1; i<10; i++){
sections.dtf_sections.["title"+String(i)].dtf_title.text = "Section" +(i)
}
```

But, it does not.

Am I missing something simple here?

The reason why they are within the movieclips is masking, and appearing at different times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing dtf_sections the wrong way.If you want to manipulate objects in a movieclip. Using the dictionary reference. You do it without the '.' .Try this hope it works for you:

```
for(var i:uint=1; i<10; i++){
sections.dtf_sections["title"+String(i)].dtf_title.text = "Section" +(i)
}
```